# Power BI :: Create column in table that queries REST API based on elements

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, azure-rest-api

I'm using the [Azure Cost Management connector in Power BI Desktop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-connect-azure-cost-management) to query our Azure Portal and pull data from the Cost Management.

**GOAL:** I would like to create a column with the 3 year Reservation so we can forecast what we could spend. The data must come from the official [Azure Retail Prices overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cost-management/retail-prices/azure-retail-prices).

**REST API Query Example:** If I want to see what is the cost for a Virtual Machine D2s v4 I can query the REST API through this query:

```
https://prices.azure.com/api/retail/prices?$filter=serviceName eq 'Virtual Machines' and skuName eq 'D2s v4' and location eq 'EU West' and reservationTerm eq '3 Years'
```

If you try to paste that into Postman or a simple web browser the result will look like this:

```
{
    "BillingCurrency": "USD",
    "CustomerEntityId": "Default",
    "CustomerEntityType": "Retail",
    "Items": [
        {
            "currencyCode": "USD",
            "tierMinimumUnits": 0.0,
            "reservationTerm": "3 Years",
            "retailPrice": 1148.0,
            "unitPrice": 1148.0,
            "armRegionName": "westeurope",
            "location": "EU West",
            "effectiveStartDate": "2020-08-01T00:00:00Z",
            "meterId": "ee6e2e65-b1d2-5863-a209-c584a58606a8",
            "meterName": "D2s v4",
            "productId": "DZH318Z0CSHJ",
            "skuId": "DZH318Z0CSHJ/01DB",
            "availabilityId": null,
            "productName": "Virtual Machines Dsv4 Series",
            "skuName": "D2s v4",
            "serviceName": "Virtual Machines",
            "serviceId": "DZH313Z7MMC8",
            "serviceFamily": "Compute",
            "unitOfMeasure": "1 Hour",
            "type": "Reservation",
            "isPrimaryMeterRegion": true,
            "armSkuName": "Standard_D2s_v4"
        }
    ],
    "NextPageLink": null,
    "Count": 1
}
```

Very Good! What I need is a column with the value `"unitPrice": 1148.0,`

I found a few examples about how to do this: [Example1](https://www.burningsuit.co.uk/blog/i-have-powerquery-using-power-query-call-rest-apis), [Example2](https://www.dalesandro.net/handling-paginated-rest-api-results-with-power-query/).

But when I try to create a new column with this code:

```
Column = Web.Contents("https://prices.azure.com/api/retail/prices?$filter=serviceName eq 'Virtual Machines' and skuName eq 'D2s v4' and location eq 'EU West' and reservationTerm eq '3 Years'")
```

Power BI returns the error Failed to resolve name "Web.Contents". It is not a valid table, variable, or function name.

**IDEAL SOLUTION:** The ideal solution should be to query every single resource we have based on the
`Usage details` table so ideally the final query should look like:

```
Column = Web.Contents("https://prices.azure.com/api/retail/prices?$filter=serviceName eq ''Usage details'[meterCategory]'' and skuName eq ''Usage details'[meterName]'' and location eq ''Usage details'[location]'' and reservationTerm eq '3 Years'")
```

because I want to take from the table Usage details:

- serviceName from the column ''Usage details'[meterCategory]''
- skuName from the column ''Usage details'[meterName]''
- location from the column ''Usage details'[location]''

So how to create a column that query a REST API for each row?

If it's to hard to do that in a new column I can also accept a new table as answer.

**EDIT:** Let me add here the Unit price table:

| subscriptionName | resourceGroupName | ResourceName | meterCategory | meterName | meterSubCategory | product | productId | consumedService | serviceFamily | Sum of costInBillingCurrency | Year | Month | location | meterId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| infra - Contoso | My-Resource-Group | VM-1 | Virtual Machines | D4ds v4 | Virtual Machines Ddsv4 Series Windows | Virtual Machines Ddsv4 Series Windows - D4ds v4 - EU West | DZH318Z0CSHH006Q | Microsoft.Compute | Compute | 9.28 CHF | 2022 | September | EU West | 48889cbd-650c-56c1-a66b-c5ca1d84fbd9 |
| infra - Contoso | My-Resource-Group | VM-10 | Virtual Machines | D2s v4 | Virtual Machines Dsv4 Series | Virtual Machines Dsv4 Series - D2s v4 - US East | DZH318Z0CSHJ0051 | Microsoft.Compute | Compute | 1.95 CHF | 2022 | September | US East | c04e5d97-2de2-5244-b91a-1e57a0a49a61 |
| infra - Contoso | My-Resource-Group | VM-11 | Virtual Machines | D2s v4 | Virtual Machines Dsv4 Series | Virtual Machines Dsv4 Series - D2s v4 - US East | DZH318Z0CSHJ0051 | Microsoft.Compute | Compute | 1.95 CHF | 2022 | September | US East | c04e5d97-2de2-5244-b91a-1e57a0a49a61 |
| infra - Contoso | My-Resource-Group | VM-12 | Virtual Machines | D2s v4 | Virtual Machines Dsv4 Series Windows | Virtual Machines Dsv4 Series Windows - D2s v4 - DE West Central | DZH318Z0CP0700SP | Microsoft.Compute | Compute | 4.21 CHF | 2022 | September | DE West Central | 0fa07af6-1ac7-5027-8ab7-ee9997c4a9fe |
| infra - Contoso | My-Resource-Group | VM-13 | Virtual Machines | D2s v5 | Virtual Machines Dsv5 Series | Virtual Machines Dsv5 Series - D2s v5 - US East | DZH318Z08M9W0061 | Microsoft.Compute | Compute | 1.95 CHF | 2022 | September | US East | 36cc2454-47d7-517f-884f-be4d6b7efa55 |
| infra - Contoso | My-Resource-Group | VM-14 | Virtual Machines | D2s v5 | Virtual Machines Dsv5 Series | Virtual Machines Dsv5 Series - D2s v5 - US East | DZH318Z08M9W0061 | Microsoft.Compute | Compute | 1.95 CHF | 2022 | September | US East | 36cc2454-47d7-517f-884f-be4d6b7efa55 |

Here you can find the `meterCategory`, the `meterName` and the `location`

Comment: Can you paste your source table Usage details

Comment: OK, I will do that in minutes

Comment: I have supplied an answer in the meantime. Let me know if you need it updating with your source table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go. FYI, your last two rows produce errors so I think there is a problem with the sample data.

[image]

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("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", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [subscriptionName = _t, resourceGroupName = _t, ResourceName = _t, meterCategory = _t, meterName = _t, meterSubCategory = _t, product = _t, productId = _t, consumedService = _t, serviceFamily = _t, #"Sum of costInBillingCurrency" = _t, Year = _t, Month = _t, location = _t, meterId = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"subscriptionName", type text}, {"resourceGroupName", type text}, {"ResourceName", type text}, {"meterCategory", type text}, {"meterName", type text}, {"meterSubCategory", type text}, {"product", type text}, {"productId", type text}, {"consumedService", type text}, {"serviceFamily", type text}, {"Sum of costInBillingCurrency", type text}, {"Year", Int64.Type}, {"Month", type text}, {"location", type text}, {"meterId", type text}}),

 #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", each let
    Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://prices.azure.com/api/retail/prices?$filter=serviceName eq '"&[meterCategory]&"' and skuName eq '"&[meterName]&"' and location eq '"&[location]&"' and reservationTerm eq '3 Years'")),
    Items = Source[Items],
    Items1 = Items{0}[unitPrice]
in
    Items1)
in
    #"Added Custom"
```

Here is the code for just the custom column:

[image]

```
let
    Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://prices.azure.com/api/retail/prices?$filter=serviceName eq '"&[meterCategory]&"' and skuName eq '"&[meterName]&"' and location eq '"&[location]&"' and reservationTerm eq '3 Years'")),
    Items = Source[Items],
    Items1 = Items{0}[unitPrice]
in
    Items1
```

Comment: Hi David and thank you so much for your effort. The data are loading, Creating a column will make a query for each row we have so it's very slow. A table would have been better but I cannot make it. Tons of errors are loaded and that might be because lot of resources don't have Reservation so the API is probably returning a `null` I believe. Do you do consulting? I mean, could I pay you a few hours to get this done? I would like to submit you a CSV with a sample of the data. Let me know how much do you charge

Comment: Hi Francesco - feel free to reach out to me on LinkedIn.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to speed this up BTW due to the nature of an API call per row.

Comment: Yes, but maybe there is a way to create a table that takes all our resources once with the price and then reference the table.

Comment: I would mark this as solved and ask a new question if I were you - then you can start fresh with your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

The following works for me. Paste into a blank query and it should be enough for you to copy for your own scenario.

[image]

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WCsssKilNzFHwTUzOyMxLLVbSUXIxKlYoMwEyXEMVwlOLS5RidYhUFwsA", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [meterCategory = _t, meterName = _t, location = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"meterCategory", type text}, {"meterName", type text}, {"location", type text}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", each let
    Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://prices.azure.com/api/retail/prices?$filter=serviceName eq '"&[meterCategory]&"' and skuName eq '"&[meterName]&"' and location eq '"&[location]&"' and reservationTerm eq '3 Years'")),
    Items = Source[Items],
    Items1 = Items{0}[unitPrice]
in
    Items1)
in
    #"Added Custom"
```

Comment: Hello, I don't get it David, Of course a blank query is returning me the same picture as you pasted. I don't understand why because there is no `D2s v4` in the code.

Comment: The D2s v4 is my sample data which is in the first line but compressed. You need to disregard the first line and use the rest of the code.

Comment: I'll add another answer with your sample data (which will again be compressed in that first line)

Comment: OK, I will try that. Also using the same code to add a column doesn't work: https://snipboard.io/zdMqsG.jpg it says: `Failed to resolve name 'Web.Contents'. It is not a valid table, variable, or function name.`